# The content of the two sandbox in codesandbox.io is the same, but the output of the browser is different (Solved)

Tags: vue.js, element-ui, codesandbox, tiptap

I have two forked sandbox in codesandbox.io. Although these two sandboxes forked from different places, but I have modified them to use the same package and content.

I wonder why the output results of these two codesandbox are different.

[image: Differences between the first sandbox and the second sandbox]
First forked sandbox url. [forked codesandbox 001](https://codesandbox.io/s/el-tiptap-el-table-first-sandboxbubblecoveredbytable-forked-tmr4l)

Second forked sandbox url. [forked codesandbox 002](https://codesandbox.io/s/el-table-el-tiptap-ceshide-demo-forked-k8c1u)

> **Updated**
>
> ---
>
> I did not notice that there is an index.css inside the
> internal resources (hard to notice if careless), which caused the difference. Thank you @User28 for
> your reminder.

[image: second sandbox is missing this]
***Your help is greatly appreciated, thank you very much.***

Comment: Your both codesandbox have same error `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Comment: I think I found it it seems the second codesandbox missing external resources which is https://unpkg.com/element-ui@2.13.0/lib/theme-chalk/index.css

Comment: Thanks @User28, hello, you are correct. After adding the missing external resources to the second sandbox, both layouts are now synchronized. Below is the modification of the second sandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/el-table-el-tiptap-ceshide-demo-add-theme-chalk-forked-p1e3t
Would you mind telling me how do you know this external css is missing? Because I did not found any related resources included in the first codesandbox.

Comment: It is included in the first codesandbox (located at `SandboxInfo` panel, under `Dependencies` section) the section was called `External resources`.

Comment: @User28 , I found it, thanks a lot!